# How can I view the list of non-stop flights between two airports as well as their schedule, including the flights canceled because of COVID-19?

Tags: air-travel, covid-19, timetables

I wonder how I can view the list of non-stop flights between two airports as well as their schedule, including the flights canceled because of COVID-19.

---

What I have unsuccessfully tried so far:

1. The Wikipedia pages for airports often has the list of non-stop flight departing from the airport,  but not the schedule (i.e., at what time and on which days the flight occurs).
2. The official airline websites typically don't mention flights canceled because of COVID-19 on their booking pages.
3. https://www.flightconnections.com doesn't mention the time of the flights.

One can approximate "cancelled due to COVID-19" by considering any air service that existed at the end of 2019 but doesn't exist any more. It is otherwise is conceivable that someone compiled the list of cancelled flights due to COVID-19, which would already be good step to answer this question.

Comment: How are you defining "cancelled due to COVID-19"?  Does that include any air service that existed at the end of 2019 but doesn't exist any more?

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Thanks, good point, yes, that'd be a good approximation.

Comment: So you're basically just looking for flight schedules as of the end of 2019, plus any routes added since then?

Comment: @ajd yes, correct

Comment: Flights change all the time. They changed before Covid, and they will change after Covid. Some flights operate only in certain days or at certain times of the year. Routes are created or stopped based on business opportunities. The number of flights is expanded or reduced, schedules are updated, smaller or larger aircraft are used. So the only thing you can do is look at planned schedules for a specific date in the future or actual schedules on a specific date in the past. And then it’s a duplicate of “how to get historical flight data”.

Comment: @jcaron thanks, COVID was particularly disruptive for flight routes, and I'm only interested in precovid typical schedule, not all history. For example, it is conceivable that someone compiled the list of cancelled flights due to COVID-19, which would already be good step to answer this question.

Comment: Just use the usual tools for historic flight data (FR24, FlightAware, flighstats…) on a few dates in 2019.  Make sure you look at all days of the week, and during various periods of the year, some routes have significant variability over the year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll summarize the answers the question received in the comments: 1) Just use the usual tools for historic flight data (FR24, FlightAware, flighstats) and look at pre-COVID data 2) Find the list of cancelled flights due to COVID-19.

---

> - Just use the usual tools for historic flight data (FR24, FlightAware, flighstats…) on a few dates in 2019. Make sure you look at all days of the week, and during various periods of the year, some routes have significant variability over the year. – [jcaron](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/30703/jcaron) [Mar 13 at 12:51](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/172562/how-can-i-view-the-list-of-non-stop-flights-between-two-airports-as-well-as-thei#comment430644_172562)
> - It is conceivable that someone compiled the list of cancelled flights due to COVID-19 – [Franck Dernoncourt](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1810/franck-dernoncourt)
>   [Mar 13 at 0:42](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/172562/how-can-i-view-the-list-of-non-stop-flights-between-two-airports-as-well-as-thei#comment430639_172562)